# I am getting all scores as 100% on my machine learning models. Is it okay to have this kind of result?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science-model, accuracy

I am getting all scores for my ML model as 100% for the Extra Trees Algorithm. I am applying the necessary pre-processing steps (duplication removal, correlations validating, cardinality validation, and missing values handling). Is this okay to have this kind of result?

[image]

Here is my code

```
std_features_train, std_features_test , std_output_train, std_output_test = train_test_split(encoded_balanced_std_scaled_emp_data.drop("leave", axis=1),encoded_balanced_std_scaled_emp_data['leave'],train_size=0.7)

model_std = ExtraTreesClassifier()

model_std.fit(std_features_train,std_output_train)
model_predictions_std = model_std.predict(std_features_test)
model_train_score = model_std.score(std_features_train,std_output_train)
model_test_score = model_std.score(std_features_test,std_output_test)
model_f1_score = f1_score(std_output_test, model_predictions_std, average='binary')
model_precision_score=precision_score(std_output_test, model_predictions_std, average='binary')
model_recall_score=recall_score(std_output_test, model_predictions_std, average='binary')
model_r2_score = r2_score(std_output_test,model_predictions_std)
  model_mse_score=mean_squared_error(std_output_test, model_predictions_std)

  std_results_table.add_row([model_std.__class__.__name__,round(model_train_score*100,2), 
                      round(model_test_score*100,2), round(model_r2_score*100,2), 
                      round(model_mse_score*100,2), round(model_f1_score*100,2), 
                      round(model_precision_score*100,2), 
                      round(model_recall_score*100,2)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is an indication of data leakage. You should check if your test dataset may contain data from your training dataset (e.g. by splitting the datasets after performing oversampling)

Answer (score 0):

This could indicate one of two things. Either your model is overfitting to the test data, or your features fully explain your target variable. The only way to be sure would be if you had (or could obtain) another independently collected dataset and use that to test your model. If that's not practical, then use your data exploration results to investigate further. Are there predictor variables that are very highly correlated with the target? Do you get perfect results if you create another type of model, such as a logistic regression?